# Diagonalization of off-diagonal block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to find the eigenvectors of the following eigensystem

$\begin{bmatrix}
 & D^{*}\\
D
\end{bmatrix}\psi=\epsilon\,\psi$

where $ D=\mathbb{I}+\exp(i\phi_{z})\sigma_{z}+\exp(-i\phi_{x})\sigma_{x} $, with $\mathbb{I}$ being the identity matrix and $\sigma $ being the Pauli matrices. I attempt to find eigenvectors by solving the simple eigensystem

$D^{*}D\,\psi_{1}=\epsilon^{2}\psi_{1}.$

Then, I expect the eigenvectors of my problem to be

$\psi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\psi_{1}\\
\psi_{1}^{*}e^{i\mu}
\end{array}\right)$

However, I did not find a consistent phase factor $\mu$. Do you have a better idea of how to find the eigenvectors $\psi$?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right basic idea
$$
\pmatrix{&D^*\\D} \pmatrix{\psi_1\\ \psi_2} = \epsilon\pmatrix{\psi_1\\ \psi_2} \implies\\
\pmatrix{D^*\psi_2\\D\psi_1} = \pmatrix{\epsilon \psi_1\\ \epsilon \psi_2} \implies\\
\psi_2 = \frac 1 \epsilon D\psi_1, \qquad D^*D\psi_1 = \epsilon^2\psi_1 \quad (\text{if } \epsilon \neq 0)
$$
So, your solutions will have the form
$$
\psi = \pmatrix{\psi_1\\ \frac 1 \epsilon D \psi_1}
$$